# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'packages.id' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to Edit specific data from the database by using column package_id when a user clicks a button but I am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'packages.id' in 'where clause'
```

controller class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Packages;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PackageController extends Controller
{

public function EditPackage($package_id) {

        $package = Packages::findOrFail($package_id );
        return view('backend.packages.edit_package', compact('package'));
        
    }//End method

}
```

Migration

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            
            $table->id('package_id');
            $table->string('package_name');
            $table->longText('package_discription');
            $table->double('package_price');
            $table->double('advance_payment');
            $table->timestamps();
            
        });
    }
```

this is the Model Class:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Packages extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded =[];
}
```

i tried to code this function from this function that i wrote for a another components. but this function works perfecly. here it is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\PropertyType;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

class PrpertyTypeController extends Controller
{

public function EditType($id) {
        $types = PropertyType::findOrFail($id);
        return view('backend.type.edit_type', compact('types'));
        
    }//End method

}
```

if you can help me out, it would be a huge help. thanks!!

Comment: As Tim Lewis mentioned, you have to tell the model what column is going to be the `primary id` as you are not using the default `id`, so my recommendation is to ALWAYS stick to `id`, there is no need to set `package_id` when the table is called `packages`, it is obvious it is going to be a `package id`, else define the name like `user_id` (for example). This is called database normalization. And also do not NEVER name models as plural, `Package` is the right name...

Answer (score 2):

`findOrFail()`, or `find()`, etc., uses the Model's Primary Key to find a Record. By default, Models use `id`, but in your Migration you're using `$table->id('package_id');`, but you never told your Model to use that, so it's trying to use `id`.

Add this to your Model:

```php
<?php
// ...
class Package extends Model {
  // ...
  protected $primaryKey = 'package_id';
  // ...
}
```

*Note: Model names are singular, so it should be `Package`, not `Packages`*

With that change, using `Package::findOrFail($package_id);` will execute the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM packages WHERE package_id = ?
```

Documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#primary-keys